# WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC "Access is Denied", C++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, system-error

Hey there,
I've created a Modeless Dialog using ResEdit to mimic exactly the function of the Window's Color Select dialog, that is present in the default Windows "Paint" application.
I'm doing this as part of my C++ WINAPI studies.
(Seen here: http://i233.photobucket.com/albums/ee74/Lightfooted/Public/colorDialog.jpg)

The issue that I'm currently stumped at is, I cannot seem to color the backgrounds of the "PictureBox" controls during "WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC" handling. I don't know why but, the moment I try to handle WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC I get the system-error message "Access is Denied".

My Code looks like this:

```
DWORD   dwLastError;
TCHAR   lpBuffer[256];

switch(msg)
{

[...]

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:

if(dwLastError != 0)    // Don't want to see a "operation done successfully" error ;-)
::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,                 // It´s a system error
                 NULL,                                      // No string to be formatted needed
                 dwLastError,                               // Hey Windows: Please explain this error!
                 MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),  // Do it in the standard language
                 lpBuffer,              // Put the message here
                 lpBuffer -1,                     // Number of bytes to store the message
                 NULL);
[...]
}
```

There isn't even anything "incase of WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC" and I am getting the system-error "Access is Denied" in response.

I have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: What we want to see is not the (bad) handling of FormatMessage, but the actual code you used in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`

Comment: Your error checking code looks bogus, so getting a garbage error message is no great surprise.  GetLastError() is only ever valid if you use it **immediately** after a winapi function returned a failure status.  Typically a FALSE return or a NULL pointer.  No indication whatsoever that you put this code in the right place.  And GDI functions don't set the last error.  The FormatMessage() call is wrong too, secondary problem.

Comment: By the way, you should change the name of the variable `lpBuffer` to just `buffer`. Microsoft uses the prefix `lp` to indicate a variable of pointer type, but your buffer is a statically-sized array, not a pointer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is error:

```
 lpBuffer -1,
```

change it to `sizeof(lpBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR) - 1`